# LLVM get operand and lvalue name of an instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

For a LLVM IR instruction like `%cmp7 = icmp eq i32 %6 %7` I want to get all three register/symbol names (i.e. `%cmp %6 and %7`)

Now I can get string `%cmp` by command `pi->getName()` where pi is Instruction pointer. But when I try to get oprand names I got **empty string** by typing `pi->getOperand(0)->getName()`.

I tried `isa<Instruction>(pi->getOperand(0))` to check whether this is an instruction and it returned true but `pi->getOperand(0)->hasName()` returned false. Things make me feeling strange is that why both `pi` and `pi->getOperand(0)` are instructions but only `pi` has name?

Is there any thoughts I can get operand name (string `%6` and  `%7` here)by using API?

LLVM version I'm using is 3.4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Names are *optional* for LLVM instructions, and indeed the two operands of your `icmp` instruction in this case don't have a name, hence the empty string.

When you *print* an LLVM module to an .ll file then the writer allocates a `%<num>` name for each instruction to make it human-readable, but this is only something the writer does during printing, that string does not exist in the actual module.

Comment: Ok. So the only choice might be rename it all by myself and maintain a map for connection between the same name from different instructions

Comment: @MinGao the standard LLVM way of keeping tabs on instructions is just to use pointers to these instructions.

Comment: "%1"... are typically a Value in the register and do not have an address in memory.