# How to get the operand name from a load instruction in llvm IR?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to fetch %2 from the instruction '%6 = load i32* %2, align 4, !dbg !135' but the function getOperand(0)->getName() is returning empty string. How to resolve this?

Comment: That %2 is assigned at print time if the name is empty, it's not a proper name and getName() returns "", so you have the right value. I "solved" it for me by always assigning names.

Comment: @arnt, Can you tell me how you have assigned names to it?

Comment: Mostly I just pass the argument to the function that creates an instruction, e.g. [CallInst::Create()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#a3b6db7b44c4df56d5af0a8d642b16e9c), but sometimes I have to call [setName()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a35ee267850af7c235474a8c46c7ac5af) explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434771/llvm-get-operand-and-lvalue-name-of-an-instruction